# Custom URL Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been using this regex for checking urls.

```
((?:href|src)=["']?)?((https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|www\.)[a-z0-9][^@]*?)(?=&quot;|&#x27;|&lt;|[\s"'<]|$)
```

However, this matches urls enclosed in brackets
Ex: (**www.x.xom)** 
(according to the regex, only the end bracket because there are cases where there are brackets inside a url). How do I write a regex so as to ignore the outer enclosing brackets??

Strings to be matched: (www.xyz.com) - only the url and www.xyz.com?query=(abc) - the entire string and (www.abc.com?q=(params)) - the string enclosed. Existing regex has a fault where if the string is (www.xyz.com) - it matches www.xyz.com).

Comment: To clarify: you want to match _any_ URL, excluding any enclosing brackets/parentheses? Can you give us some example matches?

Comment: Sure. Strings to be matched: (www.xyz.com) - only the url and www.xyz.com?query=(abc) - the entire string and (www.abc.com?q=(params)) - the string enclosed. Existing regex has a fault where if the string is (www.xyz.com) - it matches www.xyz.com). Thanks

Comment: (You should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41899748/edit) instead of commenting.) Looks like you should look into matching _balanced parentheses_ with regex.

Comment: Yup. Any suggesstions on how to proceed.

Comment: Why are you checking a URL?

Comment: to add a hyperlink to it

Comment: I would just check, if the first character is `(` and the last character is `)` instead of creating a complicated regex.

Comment: That'll work, but i just want to know, how it can be done in regex?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/546433/3462319